# Accessing table from an object

Tags: oracle, object, plsql

Is it possible to access an existing table from an object?
Here the simplified snippet:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MYOBJ AS OBJECT(
MEMBER PROCEDURE MYEXPORT( ERRORS.ERRORS_ID%TYPE));
```

ERRORS is a table. When I write it like above I'm getting error:

```
PLS-00201 - identifier must be declared.
```

Any clue? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three issues:

1. The syntax is

   ```
   MEMBER PROCEDURE procedure_name (argument_name data_type)
   ```

   You have specified the data type but not an argument name which is why you get the error message `PLS-00201 - identifier must be declared.` as you need to specify an identifier for the argument.
2. `table_name.column_name%TYPE` declarations can be used in the PL/SQL scope but not in the SQL scope. Your object declaration is in the SQL scope so you need to fully define the data type rather than referring to a column.
3. An object must have at least one attribute.

You want:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MYOBJ AS OBJECT(
  attr1 NUMBER,
  MEMBER PROCEDURE MYEXPORT( v_errors_id NUMBER )
);
```